# Convergence of the improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

I am trying to prove the following.

Suppose that $f : [1, ∞) → \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that $$\int_1^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ converges absolutely. Prove
that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^\infty f(x^n)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0.$$

So far I have that if $x\ge 1$, then $f(x^n) \le x^{n-1} f(x^n)$.
Using $u$ substitution, it seems simple to prove that the integral converges, but I can't figure out how to incorporate the $\lim\limits_{n→∞}$ and show that it will be equal to $0$.

Can anybody help me out with this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would be easier to read if you used [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A change of variables $u=x^n$ on the upper bound gives $$\int^\infty_1 x^{n-1}f(x^n)\,dx=\frac{1}{n}\int^\infty_1f(u)du$$

Comment: Ohhh I just missed the 1/u when I changed the variables. Thank you!

Comment: 1/n I mean. I appreciate the help.